# How to save and Print new line character using SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to save data to the database with Multiline textbox.

and another process is to read from the database and prints to a text file.

My problem is:

1) when I am trying to save the data in the database as new line character its taking unusally number of spaces between two words.

Please can any body help me out how to insert new line character in to the database.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Char(13) is a carriage return and Char(10) is a line feed.

so...

```
UPDATE tblEXAMPLE
SET Contents=@FIRSTLINE + chAr(13) + chAr(10)
  + @secondline + chAr(10) + chAr(13)
  + @lastline
WHERE KEY=@PRIMARYKEy
```

Comment: but how it will work when saving data from server side code to the database

Comment: The characters should save, depending on the field type. Varchar and notes should be fine, have not tested others.